# Why is the browser not caching my static content?

Tags: apache, http, browser-cache, cache-control

I've been trying to get this to work for hours now. The browser is downloading the file every time even though the `Expires` header is set to a week from now. Also tried on Firefox, same result. How can I specify that this resource is still valid and there's no need to download it every time?

Here is the Chrome network log

[image]

Here is the Chrome headers for the javascript file.

[image]

Here is my .htaccess code. I have confirmed that mod_expire is enabled.

```
ExpiresActive On

<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$">
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Did you check for the debug tools setting to disable cache when they are active ?

Comment: Yup checked them. Google fonts are being cached.

Answer (score 1):

Change httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
          <FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|js|css)$">
                      ExpiresActive On
                      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
          </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Set cache to 2 years

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=63072000, public"
```